# jsp isn't returning anything, just a blank screen

Tags: java, html, jsp

the following jsp code returns just a blank screen on web browser... what to do?

---

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>GAURAV GOSWAMI</title>
        <%
            try
            {
                Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
                Connection con =(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quiz","root","");
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                String query = "select * from qa";
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while(rs.next())
                {
        %>

        <p><br><%rs.getString(0);%></p>
        <p><br><%rs.getString(1);%></p>
        <p><br><%rs.getString(2);%></p>
        <p><br><%rs.getString(3);%></p>
        <p><br><%rs.getString(4);%></p>

        <%
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
        %>

                <br><%e.getMessage();%>
        <%
            }
        %>

    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to see the source code generate on the web browser? It is also blank?

Answer (score 2):

You're writing the **body** in the **head** section.

Move your code in the body section, like following:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>GAURAV GOSWAMI</title>
    </head> <!-- Add this line -->
    <body>  <!-- Add this line -->
    <%
        try
        {
            Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
            Connection con =(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quiz","root","");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query = "select * from qa";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next())
            {
    %>

    <p><br><%rs.getString(0);%></p>
    <p><br><%rs.getString(1);%></p>
    <p><br><%rs.getString(2);%></p>
    <p><br><%rs.getString(3);%></p>
    <p><br><%rs.getString(4);%></p>

    <%
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
    %>

            <br><%e.getMessage();%>
    <%
        }
    %>
    </body> <!-- Add this line -->
    <!-- **** </head> *** Remove this line -->
</html>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

PS: I've marked with comments like `<!-- Add this line -->` the lines to change.

Answer (score 1):

Besides **Alessandro's** answer(do not write content into head),the jdbc driver you wrote is also incorrect

You need to use `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` instead.

So change

```
Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
```

to

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```